# Schedule a notification for inconsistent interval iOS

Tags: ios, scheduling, uilocalnotification

I'm working on an application in which i want to show a UILocalNotification for an inconsistent interval. notification will appear on the day of week user want to see i.e. user selects monday, tuesday and friday then notification will be visible on these days of each upcoming week.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is schedule multiple [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html) instances for the irregular periods in your interval. You can use the [`repeatInterval`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval) property to have each `UILocalNotification` repeat.

For your example, you could have three `UILocalNotification` instances scheduled for Monday, Tuesday, and Friday, and then set the `repeatInterval` value of each of these instances to [`NSWeekCalendarUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit).

Comment: So you are saying its not possible with single Localnotification instant

Comment: but what if the week will expand to month or year? just say don't mind. their should be a more better ways to go on.

Comment: You can change the `repeatInterval` to `NSYearCalendarUnit`?

Answer (score 0):

A `UILocalNotification` takes an `NSDate` for its `fireDate` property. Why don't you create an `NSDate` instance based on feedback from the user through the UI and use that?

To create the `NSDate` object, you could either simply call `initWithTimeIntervalsSinceNow:` using a multiple of seconds. For example, to create an `NSDate` representing the time 6 days and 5 hours from now:

```
NSDate* futureDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:6*24*60 + 5*60];
```

Or, if you need to take the user's particular calendar (remember there are many different calendars in use around the world) or timezone into account, you should also check out the [`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCalendar) and [`NSTimeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTimeZone) classes. The ['Date and Time Programming Guide'](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039-SW1) is a great walkthrough of these.

Comment: can you please help me with creating a NSDate object with such such kind of information placed in it.

Comment: i read you answer but i don't think thats what i want. let me explain again. i want to repeat notification 4 5 of what ever days user select from a week and the notification will appear again and again but if i past this object to local notification the notification will appear only once.

Comment: please if you can think of any other approach for me i will be thankful :)

Comment: Ok I think I misunderstood your issue - I've made another answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put On `AppDelegate.m` and call from enterbackground and terminal method

```
-(void)localNotification{
    UILocalNotification *scheduledAlert;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    scheduledAlert = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
    scheduledAlert.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:86400];
    scheduledAlert.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    scheduledAlert.repeatInterval =  NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSArray *arr =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Your Notification 1",@"Your Notification 2",@"Your Notification 3",nil];
    int jk = arc4random()%arr.count;
    scheduledAlert.alertBody = [arr objectAtIndex:jk];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:scheduledAlert];

}
```